# KnpSnappyBundle - wkhtmltopdf: CSS/images are loaded but not scripts

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

The style and the images for my generated PDF from HTML are well loaded but not the scripts.

```
twig:
        debug: '%kernel.debug%'
        strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
        form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig']
        globals:
            pathToWeb: "%kernel.project_dir%/web"

knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 5000 --no-stop-slow-scripts --enable-javascript --debug-javascript --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0
        options:    []
```

DockerFile (wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 with patched qt (I need it for headers and footers))

```
RUN apt-get install libssl1.0-dev -y
RUN cd ~
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
RUN cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/bin/
```

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Meetings manager{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('css/navbar.css')) }}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('css/general.css')) }}">
        {% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This template is then extended and images are then loaded, for example:

```
<img style="width: 100%;" src="{{pathToWeb ~ asset('image/emargement_top.png') }}">
```

It looks like javascript can be executed, If I insert

```
<script>document.write("test");</script>
```

It works, but not the other scripts.

I tried

```
    <script src="{{ absolute_url(asset('pdf/js/bootstrap.js')) }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ absolute_url(asset('pdf/js/jquery-3.3.1.js')) }}"></script>
```

and

```
    <script src="{{pathToWeb ~ asset('pdf/js/bootstrap.js')) }}"></script>
    <script src="{{pathToWeb ~ asset('pdf/js/jquery-3.3.1.js')) }}"></script>
```

It doesn't work either (I have put a local version of the scripts in the web folder as you can see)

To sump up:

- CSS works (custom css and bootstrap css)
- Images works
- Javascript can be executed
- Jquery and bootstrap scripts are not loaded (the bootstrap grid is not working)

Any ideas ?

Comment: What version of bootstrap you're using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4, i'm aware of the col problem, you need to use  .col-n instead of .col-xs-n, I will try using bootstrap 3 and I'll be back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705880/converting-twitter-bootstrap-page-into-pdf-with-wkhtmltopdf-span-issue/21152908#comment93237574_21152908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using bootstrap 4 (flexbox). This is not supported in wkhtmltopdf stable version (0.12.x). For further information [see here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3207). Unfortunately there is no development activity at the moment, so it can take a long time until this will be supported.

There are some not complete alternatives like puppeteer (doesn't have [TOC](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1778) at the moment).

Comment: It works  with bootstrap 3 ! I lost so much time with this. But there is something weird, I previously installed the 0.12.3.2 (the default one) version that did not had patched qt. I ran it thanks to xvfb, and bootstrap 4 was generated that way (but I didn't have the header and the footer)

Comment: I would suggest to install 0.12.4 or [0.12.6-dev](https://builds.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12.6-dev/) if you are using toc and 0.12.5 if you don't need it. For these versions you don't need xvfb.